How to join two tables where the entries are listed as rows in one table and as columns in the other table?
My strings begin with '1000-' and are followed by 6 natural numbers. So, '1000459347' for example.
Two strings together - differing by 1 Digit are called 'Sister Strings'. So, for example, the sister string for '1000459347' was lot '1000459348'.
There is a table called EM_MACHINE_LG that displays the sister strings in adjacent columns.



LOT1
LOT2




1000459347
1000459348



There is another table called MACHINE_LOT, that displays a different identifier for the strings known as 'LOT IDs'.
It displays entries like this:



STRING
LOT_ID




1000459347
1712371801


1000459348
1722371811



Is it possible to join these two tables together, such that I obtain a table like this?



STRING1
LOT_ID1
STRING2
LOT_ID2




1000459347
1712371801
1000459348
1722371811




Would the first table always have just 2 lots/rows ?

You can join the same table twice, but you need unique aliases.
The example below should work.
SELECT
  EM_MACHINE_LG.LOT1 AS LOT_CODE1
  SL1.LOT_ID AS LOT_ID1
  EM_MACHINE_LG.LOT2 AS LOT_CODE2
  SL2.LOT_ID AS LOT_ID2
FROM EM_MACHINE_LG
JOIN MACHINE_LOT SL1 ON EM_MACHINE_LG.LOT1 = SL1.LOT_CODE
JOIN MACHINE_LOT SL2 ON EM_MACHINE_LG.LOT2 = SL2.LOT_CODE

